# Get index of String in String Array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I want to check if a String (coming from an EditText) is part of a String Array and I need the index. I have got a TextWatcher added as TextChangedListener like the following:

inside Activity-Class:

```
private String[] randomSpanishWords = { "pueblo", "madre" };

private TextWatcher ETListener = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        int index = Arrays.asList(randomSpanishWords).indexOf(charSequence);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
};
```

in onCreate():

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(ETListener);
```

No matter what Im typing in the EditText, index is always -1. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you debugged the value of charSequence? Unless it is equal to pueblo or madre, the result will always be -1.

Comment: Yes I have... thats why I dont get it... charSequence is pueblo if I type in pueblo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert your charSequence to String with

```
charSequence.toString()
```

Or use CharSequence for your array

```
private CharSequence[] randomSpanishWords = { "pueblo", "madre" };
```

Comment: Great ! As I suspected, List.indexOf must check the class before comparing values with equals(). But I suspect this is android-specific